# How to write e2e testing for a angular project

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am completely new in angular, now working on a project Angular where e2e tests are written using protractor.
Do any one suggest how to write testcases using e2e for curd operations.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start here >> https://www.protractortest.org/#/protractor-setup. its the best place to start.